# AWS SNS to s3 in microbatches (cross account)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

We want to write SNS events to s3 in microbatches for further machine learning (training).
The SNS is hosted in another account so the idea we have right now is as follows:

SNS-->lambda (1) --->sqs---->lambda (2)---->s3

We hope to process microbatches in lambda (2) so we can write the events in to a CSV file in s3.

I would like to know if this is a good way to go, as far as i know there are no dedicated batching capabilities in SQS other than 10 events. What might be another good option for this?

Comment: Consider Kinesis to S3?  It supports batches up to 10k I believe.  If you have to use SQS, you could make lambda2 combine 10 messages into 1 and post it to an "amplifier" queue, and add a lambda3 to handle it where it would effectively be 100 messages per batch.  But that sounds a bit hackish to me and likely more work than Kinesis.

Comment: Do you wish to collate multiple messages into a single object in Amazon S3? This sounds like an excellent use-case for [Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/what-is-this-service.html).

Comment: Hi John, i carried out a few test using firehose -->s3 directly. It turns out that the output data of firehose is highly unstructered json, which turns out to be near impossible to parse well. What do you suggest we use to get structured comma separated data out of firehouse to s3?